# Calling non mocked functions for a mocked object

Tags: java, mockito

```
import java.lang.Math;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MyClass
{
  class Test {
      int a = 10;
      Test() {}
  }    
  class OtherClass
  {
     public OtherClass()
     {}

     Map<String, Double> f() {
        System.out.print("Just for testing"); 
       return new HashMap<>();
     }

     Test getT() {
         return new Test();
     }

  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    OtherClass c = mock(OtherClass.class);
    Map<String, Double> test = c.f();
    System.out.println(test.size());
    MyClass.Test t = c.getT();
    System.out.println(t);
  }
}
```

In this example I have created mock object for `OtherClass` type.
What strange for me that `c.f()` returns empty Map, meanwhile `c.getT()`
returns null. 
Could you please help me to understand this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not provide a stub for `Map`, Mockito will return an empty map. This is a documented feature, confirmed by the [JavaDocs](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Mockito.html#2):

> By default, for all methods that return value, mock returns null, **an empty collection** or appropriate primitive/primitive wrapper value (e.g: 0, false, ... for int/Integer, boolean/Boolean, ...).